# Refresh Partial view

Tags: model-view-controller, partial-views

I used `@Html.RenderAction("_DisplayImages")` to render a partial view.

```
@model List<Univems4.Models.ImageViewModel>

@foreach (var image in Model)
{
<div class="set">

    <div class="header invisible">
        <label class="edit">@image.Name</label>
        <button class="close btnDeleteImage" title="Delete">×</button>
    </div>

    <img class="img-thumbnail edit" src="data:image/bmp;base64,@image.base64string" id="@image.Id" />

</div>
}
```

Upon button click, I want to refresh this partial view. The approach I tried is by using jQuery ajax get method.

```
 $.get("/VmsMessage/_DisplayImages", null, function (data) {
                //success

                $('#bit').html(data);

            }, "html");
```

The partial view was refreshed. but it no longer responds to the events. Why?

```
$(".set").hover(function (e) {
  // do something
});

$(".edit").click(function (e) {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: It's probable that all your Javascript events are bound on page load so reloading that content doesn't do it again.

Answer (score 0):

As the html will be genrated dynamically so events are not binded on DOM load you need to do [**event delegation**](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".set",function (e) {
  // do something
});

$(document).on("click",".edit",function (e) {
  // do something
});
```